# Could not connect remotely to Postgre SQL on Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, postgresql, azure

I have a Microsot Azure Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 14 LTS.

I installed Postgres SQL and I need to allow remote login. I believe I already configured everything fine. But still when accessing remotely it gives me

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused(0x...) Is the server running on host "..." and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What I already done:

1. Added Endpoint on Micosoft Azure Control Panel to add port 5432
2. Already set `listen_addresses='*'` in my `postgresql.conf`
3. Added `host all all * md5` in `pg_hba.conf`
4. Already restarted postgresql via `sudo service postgresql restart`
5. Reload he config `invoke-rc.d postgresql reload`

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I forgot to un-comment `listen_addresses='*'`.